# UNIX FTP can create and delete file BUT CAN'T overwrite files

Tags: php, unix, nginx, ftp

I am running ubuntu / webmin / nginx server.

For some reason I can create and delete files but I can't overwrite an existing one through FTP.

Access for folder is 755.
Access for file is 644.

I get an error like this:

```
Command:    TYPE A
Response:   200 Type set to A
Command:    PORT 192,168,0,16,246,179
Response:   200 PORT command successful
Command:    STOR box.php
Response:   550 box.php: Overwrite permission denied
```

I am using FileZilla.  Everything was going well, up to last time I check few days ago.  Suddenly it is not working any more.

I have several website on the same server and all website have the same problem.

All packages are up to date.
Any idea why I can't overwrite a files

Comment: Are you using anonymous FTP or accessing as a real user?

Comment: If you're using `proftpd`, see http://serverfault.com/questions/344348/proftpd-overwrite-permission-denied-ftp-user

Comment: I am using FTP with credentials username / pwd ( only plain FTP )